# Windows Moving Data Process Details

Tags: windows, data-transfer

I've recently gathered a lot of data which I need to move from one Storage Device to another one. The problem is that i am also gathering new data while this procress takes place. My Storage is limited at the moment, so i want to know:

*When moving data from one storage device to the next one (on windows) does the data get deleted when it was sucessfully copied to the other storage device or does the deleting of the data happens while the data is still beeing moved?*

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified how you are moving the data, so here is just
a general answer:

- When moving one file, the file is only deleted from the source when
  the copy to the target is successfully finished.
- When moving a set of files, each file is deleted in turn when its copy
  is done successfully.

If you need more information, please specify the method you are using
for moving the files.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped me.
Have a nice day :)